# python sum function forloop

Tags: python, sum

I am just wondering.. How can I sum over different elements in a for loop?

```
for element in [(2,7),(9,11)] :
        g=sum(element[1]-element[0]+1)
        print g
```

If I remove 'sum', I get:

```
6
3
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to obtain? It's not very clear. Do you want the sum of all elements in the tuples? or a list of sums?

Comment: @LinusSvendsson, hmm, who correctly 'guessed' your problem?

Comment: I want the sum of -1-i+1 for all element. Eg. (11-9+1)+(7-2+1)=9

Comment: in [functional](http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html) form?

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure what you do want to get. Is it this?

```
>>> print sum(element[1]-element[0]+1 for element in [(2,7), (9,11)])
9
```

This [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) is equivalent to

```
temp = []
for element in [(2,7), (9,11)]:
    temp.append(element[1]-element[0]+1)
print sum(temp)
```

but it avoids building a list in memory and is therefore more efficient.

Comment: you are a scholar and a psychic! kudos.

Answer (score 3):

You could replace this with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/genexpr.html):

```
In [20]: sum(element[1] - element[0] + 1 for element in [(2, 7), (9, 11)])
Out[20]: 9
```

This could be simplified to:

```
In [21]: sum(y - x + 1 for x,y in [(2, 7), (9, 11)])
Out[21]: 9
```

...which I find easier to read and guarantees that each element in the list has exactly two elements. And it doesn't use unnecessary lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> sum(right-left+1 for left,right in [(2,7),(9,11)])
9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda function to map your list into a list of sums, something like this:

```
list_of_tuples = [(2,4),(5,7)]
list_of_sums = map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], list_of_tuples)
```

There are many other ways of doing the same thing, but if you have never used map or lambda functions, it's a good opportunity to learn them ;)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

```
sum(map(lambda (x,y): y-x+1 , [(2,7),(9,11)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you refer?

```
g = 0
for element in [(2,7),(9,11)] :
         g= g + (element[1]-element[0]+1)
         print g
```

`sum` only accepts [`iterable`](http://www.learningpython.com/2009/02/23/iterators-iterables-and-generators-oh-my/) object

**Update**

```
g = 0
for element in [(2,7),(9,11)] :
         g += (element[1]-element[0]+1)
print g # moved indention to show the sum
```

Comment: Is it just me, or does the return 6 9 and not just 9?

Comment: It does, but that's because the indentation's wrong on the last line ;-)